# COM Server with a missing interface

Tags: com, interface

I have a old version of a executable COM server, and I need create a document to describe this interface. I don't have the .tlb file neither the .idl file. Can I recover the interface of a executable COM server? It's wrote in VB6.

Comment: Sometimes the type library is embedded in the .exe/DLL. You can try to see if it is by trying to open it with the OleView.exe utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB6 follows the common practice of embedding the type library as a resource in the executable.  Good place for it, it ensures that the type library always matches the COM server implementation.

Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt and run Oleview.exe.  File + View TypeLib and select your program.  It will decompile the type library back to IDL.

Another way to do it is Visual Studio's File + Open + File command.  You'll see the resources embedded in the program.  Open the "TYPELIB" node and right-click the resource, Export and give it a name that ends in .tlb.  I don't think that works in the Express edition.